# Is there a way to determine why Blender is running so slow?

Tags: performance

I have a pretty large project (about 1GB, 4 scenes) and recently Blender has become too slow too use.  A couple of annoying things, other than just lagging are:

- I can not scale or move objects with the mouse, (nothing happens) so I have to type in values

I have tweaked my GPU settings several times and used this project on Windows and Linux (dual boot) and see the same problems on each.

Is there any sort of performance monitor or profiling that would be able to say what part of the project is running so slowly?

Comment: Try appending some collections or objects into a new file. That way you can check if its an object or a file setting.

Comment: Are you using Blender 2.81 by any chance? Experimental builds normally have issues because they are still in development.

Comment: Not using 2.81.  I really wish there were some way to monitor the performance of the run-time itself.

Comment: using 2.81 latest, and blend file at 495k take forEVER to load, which is highly unusual for blender,is this all just a dev issue ? Whats affecting blend files therefore to load so slow..Overall very pleased with decimate that has been very smart at reducing my 2.5mil face mesh to a very livable size for game dev testing :)

Answer (score 0):

Another guess would be that it could be an issue with the hardware. Perhaps the CPU is having a hard time because of the number of cores? Another possible theory is that there are other programs in the background taking up all of the extra resources to speed things along. Another possibility is that the number of vertices in the scene is high that it lags. You may have to, as neighborlee suggested, to do something to reduce the high poly count.